# Compiler says I do not have a matching overloaded operator but I do

Tags: c++, templates, data-structures, operator-overloading

I am making a program that analyzes "roads" (edges of a graph) and "cities" (nodes in a graph) and then prints out the minimal spanning tree for each connected subcomponent of the graph.

I am not allowed to use STL libraries so i have to implement my own min-heap. I implemented a template min-heap so i can make a priority queue of the minimum cost roads. In the pop operation of the heap it also restructures the tree so that the top is the minimum. It has worked perfectly when i make a minHeap but now that i tried to make a minHeap of the roads it is giving me the following error:

```
error: no match for 'operator<=' in 'lastE <= *(((minHeap<Road>*)this)->minHeap<Road>::heap + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)child) * 16u)))'|
```

As well as a TON of warnings (see below).

Here is the code for the minHeap:

```
#ifndef MIN_HEAP
#define MIN_HEAP

template<class T>
class minHeap{

public:
    minHeap(int);
    void push(const T&);
    void pop();
    T top();
    void doubleHeapCap();
    bool isEmpty();
    T *heap;
    int heapSize;
    int capacity;

};

#endif

template<class T>
minHeap<T>::minHeap(int theCapacity = 10){

    if(theCapacity < 1) throw "Capacity must be >=1.";
    capacity = theCapacity;
    heapSize = 0;
    heap = new T[capacity + 1]; //heap [0] is not used

}

template<class T>
void minHeap<T>::push(const T& e){
//inserts e into min heap
    if(heapSize == capacity){ //doubles capacity if Heap is too small
        this->doubleHeapCap();
        this->capacity *=2;
    }

    int currentNode = ++heapSize;

    while(currentNode != 1 && heap[currentNode/2] > e){
        //bubble up node
        heap[currentNode] = heap[currentNode/2]; //moves parent down
        currentNode /= 2; //moves current node
    }

    heap[currentNode] = e;

}

template<class T>
void minHeap<T>::pop(){
//Deletes smallest element from heap and restructures heap
    if(isEmpty()) throw "Heap is empty. Cannot delete.";

    //deelt smallest element
    heap[1].~T();

    //remove last element from heap
    T lastE = heap[heapSize--];

    //trickle down to restructure heap
    int currentNode = 1; //root of heap
    int child = 2; // first child of heap

    while(child <= heapSize){

        //set child to smaller child of currentNode
        if(child < heapSize && heap[child] > heap[child+1]) child++;

        //can we put lastE in currenNode?
        if(lastE <= heap[child]) break; //yes we can

        //no we can't, Obama
        heap[currentNode] = heap[child]; //move child up
        currentNode = child; child *= 2; // move a level down
    }

    //after you finally find one, place the node in the corrent position
    heap[currentNode] = lastE;
}

template<class T>
T minHeap<T>::top(){
    return heap[1];
}

template<class T>
bool minHeap<T>::isEmpty(){
//says whether or not hear is empty
    if(heapSize == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

template<class T>
void minHeap<T>::doubleHeapCap(){

    int currentcapacity = this->capacity;
    int newCapacity = (this->capacity)*2;
    T *temp;
    T *newHeap;

    //create a new heap with twic the size
    newHeap = new T[newCapacity + 1];

    //copy elements over
    for(int i=0; i<=capacity; i++){
        newHeap[i] = this->heap[i];
    }

    //delete the old heap
    temp = heap;
    heap = newHeap;
    newHeap = 0;

    delete[] temp;
}
```

Here is the code for the main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include"road.h"
#include"region.h"
#include"minHeap.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int numCities;
    int numOldRoads;

    cin >> numCities;
    cin >> numOldRoads;

    minHeap<Road> roadHeap(numOldRoads);
    minHeap<Region> regionHeap(numCities);

    for(int i=0; i<numOldRoads; i++){
        int tempCityA, tempCityB;
        double tempLength;

        cin >> tempCityA;
        cin >> tempCityB;
        cin >> tempLength;

        cout << "NEW ROAD: " << tempCityA << " " << tempLength << " " << tempCityB << endl;

        Road *road = new Road;

        road->setCityA(tempCityA);
        road->setLength(tempLength);
        road->setCityB(tempCityB);

        roadHeap.push(*road);
    }

    for(int i=1; i<=roadHeap.heapSize; i++){
        Road tempRoad;

        tempRoad = roadHeap.top();
        roadHeap.pop();

        cout << "ROAD: " << tempRoad.getCityA() << " " << tempRoad.getLength() << " " << tempRoad.getCityB();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the code for the road.h:

```
#ifndef ROAD_H
#define ROAD_H

class Road{

public:
    void setCityA(int);
    const int getCityA() const;

    void setCityB(int);
    const int getCityB() const;

    void setLength(double);
    const double getLength() const;

    friend bool operator<(const Road&, const Road&);
    friend bool operator>(const Road&, const Road&);
    friend bool operator>=(const Road&, const Road&);
    friend bool operator>=(const Road&, const Road&);

private:
    int cityA;
    int cityB;
    double length;



};

#endif
```

Here is the code for the road.cpp (where i overload the operator that it says i do not have):

```
#include"road.h"

void Road::setCityA(int x){
    this->cityA = x;
}

const int Road::getCityA() const{
    return this->cityA;
}

void Road::setCityB(int x){
    this->cityB = x;
}

const int Road::getCityB() const{
    return this->cityB;
}

void Road::setLength(double x){
    this->length = x;
}

const double Road::getLength() const{
    return this->length;
}

bool operator<(const Road &lhs, const Road &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.getLength() < rhs.getLength()) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

bool operator>(const Road &lhs, const Road &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.getLength() > rhs.getLength()) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

bool operator<=(const Road &lhs, const Road &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.getLength() <= rhs.getLength()) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
bool operator>=(const Road &lhs, const Road &rhs)
{
    if(lhs.getLength() >= rhs.getLength()) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

I just struggled a ton getting the operators to work (having to deal with const errors and stuff like "cv-qualifiers and junk). In any case after finally getting it to work i thought it would be a matter of copying and pasting and modifying the operator that operators on length but it is giving me this strange error saying i haven't defined the <= operator

It also seems to be referring to the right hand side strangely, why is it referencing it like this?

```
*(((minHeap<Road>*)this)->minHeap<Road>::heap + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)child) * 16u)))
```

Lastly here is the full build messages, i feel like there is a lot of information here but being so new i can't seem to parse it:

```
warning: 'bool operator>=(const Road&, const Road&)' is already a friend of class 'Road' [enabled by default]
In instantiation of 'void minHeap<T>::pop() [with T = Road]':
|required from here
error: no match for 'operator<=' in 'lastE <= *(((minHeap<Road>*)this)->minHeap<Road>::heap + ((sizetype)(((unsigned int)child) * 16u)))'
note: candidates are:
note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator<=(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   'Road' is not derived from 'const std::pair<_T1, _T2>'
note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<=(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   'Road' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<=(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   'Road' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>'
note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   'Road' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<=(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   'Road' is not derived from 'const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>'
note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<=(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
note:   mismatched types 'const _CharT*' and 'Road'
In instantiation of 'void minHeap<T>::doubleHeapCap() [with T = Road]':
required from 'void minHeap<T>::push(const T&) [with T = Road]'
required from here
warning: unused variable 'currentcapacity' [-Wunused-variable]
```

Comment: Can you please mark in the posted source which line the compiler complains about.

Comment: Wall of code crits you for 9001 dmg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your header has:

```
friend bool operator>=(const Road&, const Road&);
friend bool operator>=(const Road&, const Road&);
```

One of those should be `<=`.

Editorial note:  this problem is one where making an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would have immediately shown you the problem and saved you posting a question here.

Comment: Wow thanks so much! I cant believe i missed that. Now i am wonderin why it gave me the error it did and not a simple "operator>= redeclared here" error

Comment: @user0123: It did. The very first warning tells you that it's already been declared a friend.